# How to keep a thread running and not terminate when a function finishes

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have this thread where I don't want it to terminate it self when it's finished a function. Instead I want to give it another function afterwards.
`

```
t1 = new Thread(() => test());
t1.Start(); 
if(t1 finished the task )
{
   give t1 new task for exmp test2  
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can call both function in thread delegate like

```
t1 = new Thread(() =>{ test();test2();});
```

If you want to execute the test code repeatedly then you can use loop in `Test()`. You can also use [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to perform something repeatedly after any interval.

If you want to use your already created thread to save the thread creation cost then you can use `ThreadPool`

[ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Many applications create threads that spend a great deal of time in
>   the sleeping state, waiting for an event to occur. Other threads might
>   enter a sleeping state only to be awakened periodically to poll for a
>   change or update status information. The thread pool enables you to
>   use threads more efficiently by providing your application with a pool
>   of worker threads that are managed by the system, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 4 or later, you can use a `Task` instead of a thread, then you can implement this using [`Task.ContinueWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => task1());
            task = task.ContinueWith(antecedant => task2());

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for composite task to complete.");
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Composite Task completed.");
        }

        private static void task1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting task 1");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Ending task 1");
        }

        private static void task2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting task 2");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Ending task 2");
        }
    }
}
```

If you use this approach, you don't need to wait for the first task to complete before assigning it another one.